# _lua_close undefined symbols on my mac

Tags: c, lua

I have source file

```
#include <lua.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFSIZE 1024

int main() {
  char line[BUFSIZE];

  lua_State *L = lua_open();
  while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) != 0) {
    lua_dostring(L, line);
  }
  lua_close(L);
  exit(0);
}
```

Then I run `gcc luac.c`, got an error.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_lua_close", referenced from:
      _main in luac-9bbdf6.o
  "_lua_dostring", referenced from:
      _main in luac-9bbdf6.o
  "_lua_open", referenced from:
      _main in luac-9bbdf6.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

It seems like that I have no `lua.h` in my `/usr/local/include` folder. But it have.

```
ls -al /usr/local/include/lua.h 
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root  admin    11K Apr  3 16:23 /usr/local/include/lua.h
```

And I have

```
ls -al /usr/local/lib/liblua.a
-rw-r--r--  1 root  admin  150448 Apr  3 16:23 /usr/local/lib/liblua.a
```

The gcc search path

```
gcc -Xlinker -v 
(#)PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:ld64-305
configured to support archs: armv6 armv7 armv7s arm64 i386 x86_64 x86_64h armv6m armv7k armv7m armv7em (tvOS)
Library search paths:
    /usr/lib
    /usr/local/lib
Framework search paths:
    /Library/Frameworks/
    /System/Library/Frameworks/
...
```

Why gcc says error, can you tell me.

---

### Updated:

The problem is gcc default doesn't add lua lib?

I use `gcc luac.c -llua -llualib`, works.

Comment: You don't actually *link* with the Lua library? Also see [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: I doesn't know, I will check the link.

Comment: "It seems like that I have no lua.h..." The compiler doesn't complain about missing file here. So obviously you have the header in your include path.

Comment: Yes, it's the link can't find `liblua.a`, I add the path to `gcc`, The problem solved, thx~

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib` and compile,  no need to specify manually

Comment: Yes, you are right.